# Changing the value of a outer class member via a inner class

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to manipulate a an outer class member via an inner class event handling method.

A class `MyColorChooser` has a private member `sliderColor`. The default value of `sliderColor` is set to black in the constructor.

An inner class is used to handle the construction of new colors via user input from `JSliders`. I then set the value of `sliderColor` to this new colour via a setter method in the outer class.

Problem is that an instance of the outer class uses its own `getColor` method which always returns the value set by the constructor (black), and not the new value it has been assigned. How can I make it so that the inner class method is able to directly alter the value in the outer member variable?

UPDATED

yes it seems like it should be working but got me stumped why its not......have posted soem of what i belive are the relevant bits f code:

NB Apologies in advance if code unsuitable as wasnt sure how much to insert....

Debugging: 
i have debugged and noted that colour is the colour it should be in the inner class and also the setColour outerclass method...so im suspecting its been changed Back to the default constructor value...just not sure where or by what...ill just keep debugging

Class MyColorChooser with which allows creation of color object via input fom JSliders handled by a inner class event hander:

```
* Part 4 
* JPanel subclass that alloews the user define the color attributes for shapes 
* utlising 3 JSliders 
*/ 
package Assignment2; 

import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.GridLayout; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JSlider; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener; 

/** 
* 
* @author Ciaran Mooney dancingbush@gmail.com 
*/ 
public class MyColorChooser4 extends JPanel { 

//declare instance varibles 
//JSlider colors 
private JSlider blueSlider; 
private JSlider greenSlider; 
private JSlider redSlider; 
//display color chossen by user varibles 
private JTextField redChoice; 
private JTextField greenChoice; 
private JTextField blueChoice; 
private DrawPanel shapeColor = new DrawPanel(); //set color of drawpanel onbject 
//prompts for user input 
private JLabel redInput; 
private JLabel blueInput; 
private JLabel greenInput; 
//color object created 
private Color colorChoice ; ; 
private JTextField theColor; 

//no arg GUI construtor gets user input and constructs color 
public MyColorChooser4() { 

//default layout of panel is set to GridLayout 4 cols 4 rows 
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4)); 


greenInput = new JLabel("Green: "); 
greenSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 1); 
greenChoice = new JTextField("0", 4);//default text 
greenChoice.setEditable(false); 

add(greenInput); 
add(greenSlider); 
add(greenChoice); 

redInput = new JLabel("Red: "); 
redSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 1); 
redChoice = new JTextField("0", 4);//default text 
redChoice.setEditable(false); 

add(redInput); 
add(redSlider); 
add(redChoice); 

blueInput = new JLabel("Blue: "); 
blueSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 1); 
blueChoice = new JTextField("0", 4);//default text 
blueChoice.setEditable(false); 

add(blueInput); 
add(blueSlider); 
add(blueChoice); 

//set default color black and declare inner class event handlers 
//sliders utlise ChengeListeners 

greenSlider.addChangeListener(new SlideHandler()); 
redSlider.addChangeListener(new SlideHandler()); 
blueSlider.addChangeListener(new SlideHandler()); 

colorChoice = Color.RED; 

//label to diplay color chosen, and blnk JLabel to move color to center 
theColor = new JTextField(4); 
JLabel preview = new JLabel(" "); 
add(preview); 
add(theColor); 
theColor.setBackground(colorChoice); 


}//end GUI constructor 

//set color 
public void setSlideColor(Color colorSlide) { 
colorChoice = colorSlide; 

}//end set colorChoice 

//get methods for fields 
public Color getColor() { 

return colorChoice; 

}//end getColor 

//return slider for red value 
public JSlider getRedSlider() { 
return redSlider; 
}//edn get red slider 

//retirn slider for green value 
public JSlider getGreenSlider() { 
return greenSlider; 
}//edn getGreenSlider 

//return slider for blue value 
public JSlider getBlueSlider() { 
return blueSlider; 
}//end getGreenSlider 

//private inner class for event handliing on sliders & implement abstract class 
private class SlideHandler implements ChangeListener { 

private Color colorSlide; 

@Override 
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) { 

//return integers from sliders 
int blue = blueSlider.getValue(); 
int green = greenSlider.getValue(); 
int red = redSlider.getValue(); 

//now construct a new color based on these values 

colorSlide = new Color(red, green, blue); 
setSlideColor(colorSlide); 


//display integer value of color chosen in relative textfield 
//use String method valueOf to return string rep of integer 
//display chossen color in text area 
redChoice.setText(String.valueOf(red)); 
redChoice.setBackground(new Color(red, 0, 0)); 
greenChoice.setText(String.valueOf(green)); 
greenChoice.setBackground(new Color(0, green, 0)); 
blueChoice.setText(String.valueOf(blue)); 
blueChoice.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, blue)); 

//set chosen color preview 
theColor.setBackground(colorChoice); 
theColor.setText("Preview"); 


}//end stateChanged method 
}//end inner class SlideHandler 
}//end class MyColorChooser4
```

Then Class ShapePanel which is a menu for which user can select various attributes of a shape to be drawn including colour. Color determined thrught slection via a JComobobox of an array of clolor objects. The colour from MyColorCHooser4 is acquired via an instance of teh class invoking the its getColor method:

declaration and intilisation of the above

```
public DrawPanel draw = new DrawPanel(); 
private MyColorChooser4 sliderColor = new MyColorChooser4(); 

//array holding color objects 
private Color colors[] = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, 

Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 
Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED, Color.WHITE, 
Color.YELLOW, sliderColor.getColor()}; 

//array carrying color strings 
private String colorNames[] = {"Black", "Blue", "Cyan", 
"Dark Gray", "Gray", "Green", "Light Gray", "Magenta", 
"Orange", "Pink", "Red", "White", "Yellow", "Slider Color"};
```

Event handler method of class ShapePanel which allows selection of colour....

```
color = new JComboBox(colorNames); 
color.setMaximumRowCount(6); 
color.addItemListener(new ItemListener() { 

@Override 
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) { 

if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) { 
draw.setCurrentColor((colors[color.getSelectedIndex()]));; 

} //end if 
}//end itemStateChnaged 
});//end annmonouys class and action event method 

componments.add(color);
```

The instance draw of class DrawPanel sets the colour the shape shoudl be drawn in via the following set method.....

```
//set current color 
public void setCurrentColor(Color color) { 


//set currentColor from JCombox input handler 
currentColor = color; 


//generate a random startColor for Gradient color 
int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256); 
int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256); 
int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256); 

//cyclic vs acylic fill 
colorFillStyle = new Random(); 
boolean gradientShift = colorFillStyle.nextBoolean(); 



 //create gradient object 
 Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue); 
 gradientColor = new GradientPaint(10f, 10f, startColor, 350f, 350f, currentColor,         gradientShift); 


}//end set color method
```

However when the shape is drawn the colour is always red, reflecting the colour intilization value in the MyColorChooser4 constructor....

Hopefully this is somewhat useful......

Comment: How could we find the problem without seeing the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please create a simple program that illustrates what you are trying to do. You can post that code here so we can help you fill in the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@increment1 
I avoided the the singleton tactic and got wat i needed by creating all instances req in the one class and achieved the changes needed by attaching listeners to event handlers . .

My problem was i was expecting the same behaviour from two separate instances of my drawPanel class, not well thought out and inexperience.

Thanks again
C

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it is impossible to know for certain what the issue is, but there are a couple of possibilities:

1: The set method in your outer class is incorrect.  Seems unlikely, but always worth checking since perhaps it is written as:

```
public void setColor(Color color)
{
    // Should be this.color =
    color = color;
}
```

2: Your inner class is not calling the outer classes set method, perhaps the inner class has declared its own set method that takes precedence in your call.

3: The inner class is never actually being called, possibly because your event is not being triggered.

Ultimately, your setMethod is not being called, it is not doing what you think it should be doing, or something else is resetting the value after you call the set method.  As far as I can tell, these are the only possibilities for why your value would not be set as expected.

If you post your code then we can arrive at a more specific answer to your problem.

Comment: I think the prob may lie with two sep instances. 
I am using a diff instance of MyColorChooser to render the JSliders JPanel which is then added to a internal frame, I've created a sep instance in a sep class to call the getColor method.

If this is so, is it possible to use the same instance in multiple classes of the same pacakage? Is it a matter of declaring the instance static?

Comment: @dancingbush I do not write Swing components, so I am not sure if you can use the same JPanel instance twice for rendering, however if you are only rendering it once and declaring the second instance only to access the values then you can certainly share it (only concern here would be if your program is multi-threaded and you need to make the access thread safe).  Using static would be one way, but ideally you would pass your ColorChooser instance to each object that requires it, either in that object's constructor or injected via a set method.

Comment: Thanks. I controlled obj creation using a singleton class of MyColorChooser to ensure two objects are sharing the same colour....and I now clearly see that when the instance is created of MyColorChosser4 it contains all the DEFAULT values of this class ie color=RED. But when I look in the class itself I see the color has changed according to the JSlider input......so somehow a instance of the class has none of the values that the class has in its current state.....

Comment: @dancingbush FYI, singletons are often considered an anti-pattern (although they arguably have their place for convenience).  If you are going to use one, I would suggest you refer to it via an interface, and inject the actual instance of the singleton into the classes that use it where possible instead of having those classes refer to it statically.  This allows for it to be easily mocked out and replaced when unit testing.  This is general advice though, and may not apply to your specific situation and code.